# Append Pandas object at the top of another object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to append this Pandas object :

```
'one' : <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

into this Pandas object :

```
'df' : <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

I used `df = df.append(one)` that works good but my 'one' elements is added at the end. How to append it at the top of my df pandas object?

Thank you

Comment: what is the shape of your dataframe, df?

Comment: when you say append a Pandas Series to a Pandas DataFrame do you mean just adding it as a column or adding it as a dataframe with nan instead of the others column values ?

Comment: `one.to_frame().append(df,sort=False)`..?